# Disable paragraphs in TextView?

Tags: android, textview

It's a simple question. How do I completely remove spacing between lines in TextView? In other words: I want to completely disable paragraphs. For example I don't want this to happen:

*Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Libero habitasse venenatis vestibulum: Fringilla ipsum penatibus vitae elementum... Sagittis eros augue commodo? Interdum nibh hendrerit sene*

*ctus sociis: Porta porta lacus nascetur scelerisque. Faucibus eleifend luctus dolor velit sodales interdum volutpat? Orci odio libero ultricies sagittis; Gravida cubilia id ut suspendisse eget. Ac ante aptent ullamcorper lacu*

Instead, I want this:

*Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Libero habitasse venenatis vestibulum: Fringilla ipsum penatibus vitae elementum... Sagittis eros augue commodo? Interdum nibh hendrerit sene ctus sociis: Porta porta lacus nascetur scelerisque. Faucibus eleifend luctus dolor velit sodales interdum volutpat? Orci odio libero ultricies sagittis; Gravida cubilia id ut suspendisse eget. Ac ante aptent ullamcorper lacu*

Comment: This has nothing to do with `TextView`. `TextView` knows nothing about paragraphs. If you do not want to show paragraphs, do not use paragraphs in the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this before putting it into the TextView

```
textContent.replace("\n","");
```

Answer (score 0):

`TextView` doesn't have this feature to remove `newline` from `paragraph` or `large` text. You have to do it `programmatically` before setting `text` into `TextView`.

Use `yourString.replaceAll(System.getProperty("line.separator"), "")` to remove `newline` from your `paragraph` text.

**Try this:**

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

// Dynamic paragraph text
String strText = ..............; // Your paragraph text from server or somewhere else
strText = strText.replaceAll(System.getProperty("line.separator"), ""); // Remove newline
textView.setText(strText);


// Static paragraph text
String strText = getResources().getString(R.string.lorem_ipsum); // Defined in strings.xml
textView.setText(strText);
```

Hope this will help~